# How to remove parts of a URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have some problem with `RewriteRule`. I'm moving old shop to new one and path to some products will be changed. The old path to one single product is:

```
www.example.com/page/product1.html
www.example.com/page/sub-page/product1.html
```

Every single product (in new shop) can be found on that path:

```
www.example.com/product1.html
```

And it is the best and (in my opinion) the easiest way to redirect all the products. How to cut the part of previous links? My rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page/sub-page/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but every time when I enter to the page using old path `www.example.com/page/sub-page/product1.html` the link after redirect looks like that: `www.example.com/sub-page/product1.html` and should `www.example.com/product1.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/sub-page/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** Or combine it a single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(?:.+?/)?([^/]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still the same `www.example.com/sub-page/product1.html`

Comment: Test it in new browser

Comment: Glad to know, I also provided you a single rule to take care of both redirects. Just in case for any future needs.

Comment: Thank once again anubhava :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch positions of your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/sub-page/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite module just goes down your list of rules and tries to apply the rule one by one. Your first rule would match both.

Comment: still the same address `www.example.com/sub-page/product1.html`